# Android Kotlin - retrofit2 set POST parameters

Tags: kotlin, retrofit, retrofit2

```
interface ApiInterface {
    @Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
    @POST("testgetmemes/")
    fun getMemes(): Call<List<Memes>>
}

object ApiClient {
    var BASE_URL:String="https://www.androidisapos.com/"
    val getClient: ApiInterface
        get() {

            val gson = GsonBuilder()
                .setLenient()
                .create()

            val client = OkHttpClient.Builder().build()

            val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .client(client)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .build()

            return retrofit.create(ApiInterface::class.java)
        }
}
```

and inside a function:

```
    val call: Call<List<Memes>> = ApiClient.getClient.getMemes()
    call.enqueue(object : Callback<List<Memes>> {

        override fun onResponse(call: Call<List<Memes>>?, response: Response<List<Memes>>) {
            setMemes(JSONArray(Gson().toJson(response.body())), gal)
        }

        override fun onFailure(call: Call<List<Memes>>?, t: Throwable?) {
            Log.d(tagg, t!!.toString())
        }
    })
```

How can I add POST Parameters (and the values ofc)? I've seen countless examples but they all construct the code of this absolutely awful library differently what makes it impossible to understand when you don't know Kotlin/Java 100%

EDIT:

I tried:

```
fun getMemes(@Query("test") test: String?): Call<List<Memes>>
```

and

```
val call: Call<List<Memes>> = ApiClient.getClient.getMemes("bla")
```

It doesn't send POST key `test` with value `bla`

Comment: Add parameters to your `getMemes()` interface function. Annotate those parameters with `@Query` or `@Body`.

Comment: @BenP. Check the question edit please

Comment: Sorry, for `POST` it would be `@Field` instead of `@Query`

Comment: Ok it works now thanks